# Separating Partial Differential Eq

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a PDE:

$$
\frac{\partial^2\phi(r,\theta)}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial\phi(r,\theta)}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2\phi(r,\theta)}{\partial\theta^2} + C^2\phi(r,\theta)=0
$$

I need to separate the PDE (just functions of r,theta) and show the relationship between the separation constants and $C^2$. I need to use solution of $\phi(r,\theta)$ = $f(r)g(\theta)$.
When I do that, then divide by solution, I do not see how I can separate $g$ from $1/r^2$ without having the $C^2$ change to $C^2r^2$.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have no idea what $+C^2(r,\theta)$ means. Would you please write out the original PDE so that it can be clearer to the rest of us?

Comment: I would but I am not sure how to use mathjax. 1/f(r)*d^2*f(r)/dr^2 + 1/f(r)*1/r*df(r)/dr + 1/g(theta)*1/r^2*d^2g(theta)/dtheta^2 + C^2 = 0.

This is after I applied solution then divided by solution

Comment: original is d^2phi(r,theta)/dr^2 + 1/r*dphi(r,theta)/dr + 1/r^2*d^2phi(r,theta)/dtheta^2 + C^2*phi(r,theta)

Comment: To write fractions, the notation is \frac{numerator}{denominator} and to write in Mathjax, put your LaTeX code in dollar signs.

Comment: $\frac{d^2phi(r,theta)}{dr^2}$
What is wrong with that?

Comment: Put one dollar sign on each side.

Comment: Good! Now to do Greek letters, you do \phi, \theta, etc. Or if you want the upper case Greek letters, \Phi, \Theta, etc.

Comment: And as a stylistic choice, do not include asterisks in LaTeX code (except in _very_ specific instances). Asterisks are generally frowned upon.

Comment: Seems like a [repeat of this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579891/partial-diffeq-separation)

Comment: I just voted to delete other post. I completely wrecked the mathjax

Comment: @CameronWilliams I need to express the separation constants in terms of C^2. Normally this is easy. However, here, the 1/r^2 must be multiplied meaning C^2 gets group in and I do not know how to make a relationship between C^2 and separation constnats

Comment: I see your point. This is a pretty tricky one to me. I'm not sure how to do it immediately. Perhaps you'll need to do some sort of Bernoulli trick for the radial part of the SoV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you suppose $\phi(r,\theta) = R(r) \Theta(\theta)$, then

$$
R'' \Theta + \frac{1}{r} R'\Theta + \frac{1}{r^2} R \Theta'' + C^2 R \Theta = 0
$$

Multiplying by $r^2$, you have

$$
r^2 R'' \Theta + r R'\Theta + R \Theta'' + r^2 C^2 R \Theta = 0
$$

Dividing by $R \Theta$

$$
\frac{1}{R}\left(r^2 R'' + r R'\right) + \frac{\Theta''}{\Theta} + r^2 C^2 = 0
$$

Then
$$
\frac{1}{R}\left(r^2 R'' + r R'\right) + r^2 C^2 = - \frac{\Theta''}{\Theta}
$$

And given that the left hand side depends only on $r$ and the right hand only on $\theta$, you have

$$
\frac{1}{R}\left(r^2 R'' + r R'\right) + r^2 C^2 = - \frac{\Theta''}{\Theta} = \lambda
$$

where $\lambda$ is a constant. Then
\begin{align}
r^2 R'' + r R' + (C^2 r^2 - \lambda) R &= 0 \\
\Theta'' + \lambda \Theta &= 0
\end{align}

The first one is a scaled version of [Bessel equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function), while the second one is the harmonic oscillator.

**EDIT**

[Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11683) is the transcript of the chat I with the OP, where a full answer is given.

Comment: I think this is close to what I was getting. I need to express separation constants just in terms of C^2 (at least that is my impression). If the 1/r^2 were not there, I could say: $\alpha^2$ + $\gamma^2$ = C^2

Comment: I'm guessing you're getting [Helmoltz equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation) from separating time and space from a cylindrical wave equation. If you need to quantize $\lambda$ and $C$, then boundary conditions are needed.

Comment: So you suspect that without boundary conditions, I cannot get an expression to show a relationship between separation constants and C^2?

Comment: Well, if by a relationship you mean $C = C(\lambda)$, then no. The solution of the system is \begin{align}\Theta(\theta) &= A e^{\sqrt{\lambda} x} + B e^{-\sqrt{\lambda} x} \\ R(r) &= C J_\sqrt{\lambda}(C x) + D Y_\sqrt{\lambda}(C x)\end{align} where $J_\sqrt{\lambda}$ and $Y_\sqrt{\lambda}$ are Bessel and Neumann functions of the first kind, of order $\sqrt{\lambda}$. If no boundary conditions are given, then you have an infinite collection of solutions spanned by both parameters.

Comment: Could I divide both sides by r^2 and R to get B^2 by itself?

Comment: Do you see a way in which I could get a^2 + b^2 = C^2?

Comment: The separation I've shown you is correct. What is $a$ and $b$? As I told you, the relationship between $C$ and the separation constant comes from the boundary conditions. Why don't you edit your question and show us how did you derived the relation $a^2 + b^2 = C^2$? [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117) is a quick guide on how to typeset equations.

Comment: $a^2$ is a constant and $b^2$ is the other constant. Together they add to $C^2$. Imagine if there hadnt have been a 1/r^2 term. We would have had the addition if two constants = $C^2$

Comment: I need to state B.C's for just r term. I did that. Then I need to write down any auxillary B.C.'s I would need to solve the problem (not including theta). I think this means I need to show a relationship.

Comment: Is there anyway to get this in Helmholtz form?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11683/discussion-between-pragabhava-and-jackson-hart)